# Where can I save log files to with Node.JS in Express framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application where I am using Winston to track some logging. I want to have a server side log in addition to the client side. In the express framework is it just the files in the public folder that are accessible to the client and if I want to do a server side log where the client users can not access it can I create a folder outside of public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, just point the log file to be outside the `/public` folder and whatever other folders you have configured in `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public_folder')));`

You can configure were the `winston` tranports will log the files by setting its proper attributes, for instance, in the `file` transport you have to set the `filename` option.

The following is a `config.js` file from I load all configuration for my logging activities (server side and client requests):

**config.json**

```
{
    "transports": {
        "console": {
            "enabled": true,

            "colorize" : true,
            "timestamp": false
        },
        "file"   : {
            "enabled": true,

            "colorize" : true,
            "filename" : "/var/log/vifros.log",
            "timestamp": true
        },
        "mongodb": {
            "enabled": true,

            "db": "vifros"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT LOGGING- logger.js -- (see comment):**

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB; // Monkeypatch Winston for MongoDb transport.

var config = require('../config');

/*
 * Enable initially all transports for initial app startup and then disable them according to settings.
 *
 * Add console transport.
 */
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console); // To being able to reconfigure it.

if (config.logging.transports.console.enabled) {
    winston.add(winston.transports.Console, config.logging.transports.console);
}

/*
 * File transport.
 */
if (config.logging.transports.file.enabled) {
    winston.add(winston.transports.File, config.logging.transports.file);
}

/*
 * Enable saving logs to mongodb.
 */
if (config.logging.transports.mongodb.enabled) {
    winston.add(winston.transports.MongoDB, config.logging.transports.mongodb);
}

exports.logger = winston;

exports.tags = {
    init       : 'init',
    api_request: 'api_request',
    db         : 'db',
    validation : 'validation',
    cross_rel  : 'cross_relationship',
    os         : 'os'
};
```

Comment: That is an awesome trick with the config file, I am just going through the docs but I have not gotten up to that part yet!

Comment: Where does the config file go, in the same directory because I can not find it in the documentation?

Comment: Oh! No, that `config` file is not part of **winston** but the options of each transport yes. The `config.js` file is one I made to store all my global config data, so when I configure the transports in the app the code remains tidy and in one single place. For instance, I use it like I pointed out in the EDIT **logging**.

Comment: I got it, pretty much use the transport to select where the log file goes. But in express what folders can the user see and not see?

Comment: Sorry, I got it!!! Why even bother putting it in express at all, just out it anywhere on the the host machine!!!!!

Comment: Exactly! This is no express related but it can stand on its own, that is why I put it in its own files.